# ¿Saben el porqué del error "EL sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado" cuando pongo la combinación Ctrl + B en Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublimetext

Estoy recién empezando, por lo que no sé cómo encontrar una verdadera solución a lo que aparece en el mensaje de error adjunto.

```
[WinError 2] EL sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\**\\Desktop\\f.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\\**\\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;]
[Finished]
```

Comment: tienes Python descargado desde la pagina oficial? o sino desde la tienda de Windows?

Answer (score -2):

Prueba agregando python al path de Windows. En este enlace se explica muy bien paso a paso como hacerlo: https://www.kyocode.com/2019/10/agregar-python-path-windows/

Comment: Esta es la zona de respuestas, no de comentarios.